# Java/HTML - prevent outlook from wrapping text in table

Tags: java, html, css, word-wrap

I have a css defined as follows:

```
body {
    font-size: 80%;
    font-family: Calibri;
}

table.gridtable {
    color:#333333;
    text-align: center;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #666666;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.gridtable th {
    border-width: 1px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #666666;
    background-color: #dedede;
}

table.gridtable td {
    border-width: 1px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #666666;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

which is subsequently loaded in my Java main method. As you can see, I am trying to prevent any wrapping within the theaders/cells. Nevertheless, when an e-mail is generated and opened in outlook, some lines are wrapped and some are not. The wrapping is also idiotic, for instance a word International is wrapped as follows: Interantio|nal... Any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score -1):

try added a space at nowrap attribute, also there are some javascript based wrap functions available, check them out.

Comment: Script in email - good luck with that.  Space at nowrap - when and how would that make a difference?